# how to bypass/disable SSLHandshake in java netbeans?

Tags: java, http, browser, https, netbeans

i am building a web browser in order to access websites not having secure protocol in it. actually my college website doesnt have a secure protocol so i want to develop a web browser of my own so i can access my college website easily.

i am getting following error when i try to access my college website

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: The server selected protocol version TLS10 is not accepted by client preferences [TLS12]
at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:357)
at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:313)
at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:304)
at sun.security.ssl.ServerHello$ServerHelloConsumer.onServerHello(ServerHello.java:946)
at sun.security.ssl.ServerHello$ServerHelloConsumer.consume(ServerHello.java:873)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:376)
at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:479)
at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:457)
at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:200)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:154)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1290)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1199)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:401)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:373)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:587)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:197)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1570)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1498)
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:352)
at javax.swing.JEditorPane.getStream(JEditorPane.java:733)
at javax.swing.JEditorPane.setPage(JEditorPane.java:432)
at javax.swing.JEditorPane.setPage(JEditorPane.java:880)
at insecurebrowser.BrowserScreen.enterURL(BrowserScreen.java:165)
at insecurebrowser.BrowserScreen.lambda$new$0(BrowserScreen.java:24)
at javax.swing.JTextField.fireActionPerformed(JTextField.java:508)
at javax.swing.JTextField.postActionEvent(JTextField.java:721)
at javax.swing.JTextField$NotifyAction.actionPerformed(JTextField.java:836)
at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.notifyAction(SwingUtilities.java:1668)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBinding(JComponent.java:2882)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindings(JComponent.java:2929)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2845)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6316)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1954)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:835)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1103)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:974)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:800)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4760)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

here is the java code i have written.

```
public class BrowserScreen extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form BrowserScreen
 */
public BrowserScreen() {
    initComponents();
    addressField.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
        enterURL(e.getActionCommand());
    });
    
    browserPane.addHyperlinkListener((HyperlinkEvent e) -> {
        if(e.getEventType() == HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED){
            enterURL(e.getURL().toString());
        }
    });
    
    refreshButton.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
        enterURL(addressField.getText());
    });
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    addressField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    refreshButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    browserPane = new javax.swing.JEditorPane();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());

    addressField.setText("URL");

    refreshButton.setText("Refresh");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(addressField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 625, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(refreshButton)
            .addContainerGap(14, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(addressField)
                .addComponent(refreshButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 32, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    jPanel2.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());

    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(browserPane);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
    jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
    jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 397, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(BrowserScreen.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(BrowserScreen.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(BrowserScreen.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(BrowserScreen.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new BrowserScreen().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

private void enterURL(String url){
    try{
        browserPane.setPage(url);
        addressField.setText(url);
    } catch(Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Not a valid url");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JTextField addressField;
private javax.swing.JEditorPane browserPane;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JButton refreshButton;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Comment: The college server seems to want to use TLS v1.0, while even v1.1 is not something Java supports (out of the box) anymore, the default being v1.3.

Comment: [1] The JDK now disables TLS 1.0 and 1.1 by default. See [JDK-8202343 : Disable TLS 1.0 and 1.1](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8202343). [2] The workarounds would be to use a version of JDK 8 or JDK 11 that hasn't implemented that fix (not good), or by messing with **java.security**. See the section titled "How do I re-enable TLS1.0 and TLS1.1..." in [this article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/tls-1-0-1-1-changes-in-openjdk-and-amazon-corretto/). [3] Once you resolve this, please be sure to post an answer with your solution. That helps the SO community.

Comment: @skomisa is there any option in which i can enable TLS1.0 and TLS1.1 from program code? because if i share my project with my classmates they will have to do the whole process in their pc so is there any other option?

Comment: If patch JDK8202343 has been applied I don't think you could enable TLS 1.0/1.1 dynamically from application code. You'd have to configure it using **java.security**. But if that patch hadn't been applied (e.g. If using a release of JRE 8 prior to update 291) you could call `setEnabledProtocols()` for `SSLEngine` or `SSLSocket` in your code. But that would require you and your classmates to be using a less secure version of the JRE which would not be good, even if it helped you with this specific issue. Unfortunately, I don't see a clean and easy solution to your problem.